# Deploy obfuscated assembly using click once

Tags: clickonce, obfuscation

Hi all
I want to obfuscate my assemlies and then publish project using click once.How I can do that?because when using click once my progect rebuild and assemblies create again.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could add a project post-build event that will run Dotfucator from the command line on each build? Perhaps only tie to the Release builds so that it is not run for every Debug build.

For instructions on running command line Dotfuscator see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227238(VS.80).aspx

That would ensure that every release build is obfuscated. And then you could reference the obsfucated assemblies in the Application files of the deploy.